# Store cookies consent

Tags: cookies, privacy

Im trying to understand what is the correct way to store my users cookies consent,

when I'm storing it as cookiesConsent at LocalStorage
 `localStorage.setItem('cookieConsent', 'true');`
the cookies are not deleted when the suer delete his cookies from the browser setting which is obviously not legal.
sessionStorage is asking for permission every new tab opening and I'm wondering what is the way to store the consent that will be deleted as the user delete his cookies from the browser.